# Pluralization of acronyms

Tags: grammatical-number, acronyms, initialisms

I have seen the following questions: [Pluralization of acronyms ending in 'S'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53579/pluralization-of-acronyms-ending-in-s), [What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym) or [Plurals of acronyms, letters, numbers — use an apostrophe or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55970/plurals-of-acronyms-letters-numbers-use-an-apostrophe-or-not)

In all of them, the plural of in the extended form goes in the end:

> One compact disk, two compact disk**s**
>
> One automated teller machines, two automated teller machine**s**

My question is, what about acronyms (or initialisms...) such as

> One rotation per hour: 1 RPH
>
> Two rotation**s** per hour: 2 ???

(Note that RPH is a home-made acronym.)
Obviously RsPH is not an appropriate choice, but *RPHs* seems a bit strange (I would be fine for rotation per hours, but maybe not for rotations per hour).

Any piece of advice?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In the scientific literature, it is customary to introduce one's own acronyms, to avoid repeating the same list of words over and over again.

Comment: Acronyms, like words, are accepted forms, not DIY contrivances. John M. Landsberg addresses abbreviations such as 1 mph; 7 mph in the 'Do you put an 's' at the end of acronym?' thread.

Comment: ELU is concerned with discussing established standard usage. If DIY abbreviations/acronyms are de rigeur in some non-mainstream registers, sites and style guides addressing such are the best places to discuss / research protocols.

Comment: 1) Even the Oxford English Dictionary lists their own abbrevations: http://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/abbreviations/. Abbrevations such as "Absol." (for absolute) and "absol." (for absolutely) seem closer to DIY contrivance than accepted form (accepted by who?). 2) The ELU page https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic is not as clear as clear-cut as your comment.